# Get only methods of an object with a condition on return type

Tags: typescript

At the start I have a class with attributes and methods. I want to filter to get **the keys of the methods only**.

I did a utility type for this and it worked fine:

```
type FunctionPropertyNames<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends (...args: any) => any ? K : never;
}[keyof T];

export type OnlyFunctionProperties<T> = Pick<T, FunctionPropertyNames<T>>;
```

Now I want to get only the keys of methods that **return a result indexable by string**, even more precisely, that have a body property. I want this because I want to write the following function with this return type.

```
public async call<K extends keyof OnlyFunctionProperties<T>>(
    method: K,
    ...params: Parameters<T[K]>
  ): Promise<ReturnType<T[K]>['body']> {
    const response = {};
    return response as any;
  }
```

I currently got the following error:

> Type '"body"' cannot be used to index type 'ReturnType<T[K]>'

I tried to modify the FunctionPropertyNames utility but no solutions so far. Here is a [ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKFBcE8AcFMAIBiBXAdgY3ASwPaoAoBOOchUAcgIYC2sAzgDwAqAfPALzwDeo88A2gGl4WVPADWsSDgBm8JgF0AXPKEL4sAB7hYqACZ14ACl594AOkuVCAczorKqSKYCUHNkRzUsdWAx4gZvAARjh6kA5OANymAL4spnwA-PCCifAqqLAAbrCEMSCx-JLScooFoFrQOGTwUHDwAPKoADaQKBjYeJ6k2PTMbJz4WOjizAA0SGiYuATEvZBUtIysLBUgVTXg8JTBdOCElJjw6C2UdIaNALIAygCC0Fg3edkjfqZMoGwBfOh4+4RkJgakY3FxYqBTNBkMEWiMdnRIBgTpQWi0GMItDp9IYSrImq12tMunMSHk+isWCwTIEzLRwAALMIqQTjdKWczQaw0ezwfDc+l5FZqBK0lwqTzeXwMABKsHAyEIqCYMD8TBF-AA5KFwpqFN90n9UPt4IR6NVjQhOOCCkEzQqlabzf8EOcdtE4qAISAgA) representing the issue.

Comment: Just noting that a type being indexable by `body` does not imply that it is indexable by `string`... it looks like you want something with a `body` property, and you don't really care if it's indexable by `string` or not.  So you probably don't want to mention "indexable by string" at all in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `ReturnType<T[K]>` will be a `Promise` of some kind, and `Promise`s tend not to have a `body` property.  You will need something like [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) to pull the `body` property out of the `Promise`d type.  Perhaps like:

```
  public async call<K extends keyof OnlyFunctionProperties<T>>(
    method: K,
    ...params: Parameters<T[K]>
  ): Promise<T[K] extends (...a: any) => Promise<{ body: infer B }> ? B : never>;
```

And you can verify that it works:

```
declare const o: OMSApiService<{
  foo: string,
  bar(x: string): number,
  baz(x: string): Promise<string>,
  qux(x: string): Promise<{ body: string, soul: number }>
}>
o.call("qux", "123").then(x => x.toUpperCase()); // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-PWbCxO-AAI7ITR9ksDhtDrUj-whMIRBeEMvjOg4ZBNdKt9uEc1R0U4czoFFNIwAIhnmjv4zvAEYAEwAZjvLnMDN0NbuPAmh-jgACq0CkAAwqcsDAi4UTwAA9Eh8A4OIlCQEAA)